# Eclipse C++ for Mac settings (<iostream> fix) and error correction

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I am testing out eclipse C++ for Mac. I have three specific questions.

1. This is the classic iostream problem for Mac. It does not know where to find it. So in the project properties I add the path where iostream is located (Preferences->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols->includes). Now iostream works. But I am trying to find a way where I don't have to do this for every new project. Is there a specific setting I can select to include this directory automatically for each new project?
2. Is xCode necessary for eclipse to work? If yes, how can I get eclipse to work without it? xCode takes up 6 GBs.
3. I'm getting an error on a test project (see below) that I'm not sure how to fix. Something about "linker command failed". I seem to be able to compile regular C programs fine though. Note this project works fine in Visual Studio.

   23:37:30 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project pointClass ****
   make all 
   Building target: pointClass
   Invoking: MacOS X C++ Linker
   g++  -o "pointClass"  ./point.o ./test.o
   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
     "std::istream::operator>>(double&)", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
     "std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
         Point::Point(double, double) in test.o
         Point::Point(Point const&) in test.o
     "std::ostream::operator<<(double)", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
         Point::Point(double, double) in test.o
     "std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
     "std::ios_base::Init::Init()", referenced from:
         ___cxx_global_var_init in test.o
     "std::ios_base::Init::~Init()", referenced from:
         ___cxx_global_var_init in test.o
     "std::cin", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
     "std::cout", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
         Point::Point(double, double) in test.o
         Point::Point(Point const&) in test.o
     "std::basic_ostream >& std::endl >(std::basic_ostream >&)", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
         Point::Point(double, double) in test.o
         Point::Point(Point const&) in test.o
     "std::basic_ostream >& std::operator<< >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
         Point::Point(double, double) in test.o
         Point::Point(Point const&) in test.o
     "std::basic_ostream >& std::operator<<, std::allocator >(std::basic_ostream >&, std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&)", referenced from:
         _main in test.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
   make: *** [pointClass] Error 1

Comment: "Is xCode necessary for eclipse to work?" ... Why would you need it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same with Eclipse